# RTL collectionView using UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

I'm trying to find a way to have a right to left `UICollectionView` using `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` but there's no documentation about it. has anybody an idea?

please recommend anything than flipping the `UICollectionView` and the cells.

Comment: it works for me: (set in a correct lifecycle)
collectionView.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft

Comment: @MaziarSaadatfar can you give me an example. what do u mean from correct lifecycle

Comment: it depends on your usage if you use in tableviewcell you must set it to layoutSubviews() and if you use it in viewcontroller you must use in after viewdidload, now I try it in my code in tableviewcell, my collection view is horizontal

Comment: @MaziarSaadatfar Thanks Maziar. you can send it as an answer so i accept your solution layoutSubviews did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it depends on your usage if you use in tableviewcell you must set it to layoutSubviews() and if you use it in viewcontroller you must use in after viewdidload lifecycle

```
collectionView.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add below lines in your view controller.

```
extension UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    
    open override var flipsHorizontallyInOppositeLayoutDirection: Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

This is extension that over-ride and allow to flip horizontally for RTL layout.

Comment: I’m making an component so i have no acces to VC.

Comment: collection view is in a Uiview

Comment: no issue. add in the first VC.

Comment: Fahim i am making a component there s no VC here. just a subclass of UIView and theres a UICollectionView as subview. no VC here!

Comment: @Mehrdad : Then put inside UIView. Where is the issue? Just have this line and check once...

Comment: ok let me check

Comment: it didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick it works for me:

```
    collectionView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1)
```

and in cellForItemAt :

```
    cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1)
```

Comment: thanks Maziar. but as i told i’m not looking for flipping the collection and cells using Transform. i need Compositional Layout handles the RTL layout itself.